# Creating BigQuery table column with BIGNUMERIC data type using Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bignum, spring-cloud-gcp

When creating BigQuery tables using the Java ***com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery*** library, I don't see the ***BIGNUMERIC*** column data-type in the **StandardSQLTypeName** enumerations. I see ***NUMERIC*** but not ***BIGNUMERIC***. How would I create a table with a BIGNUMERIC column programmatically? Thanks!

```
  Field f1 = Field.newBuilder("first_name", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING).build();
  Field f2 = Field.newBuilder("score", StandardSQLTypeName.NUMERIC).build();
  Schema schema = Schema.of(Arrays.asList(f1,f2));

  TableId tableId = TableId.of("my_data_set", "tbl_people"));
  TableDefinition tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.of(schema);
  TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(tableId, tableDefinition).build();

  bigQuery.create(tableInfo);
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, were you able to update to the latest version of **com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery** library and use the `BIGNUMERIC` enum? If yes, consider accepting the answer so the community knows if you've been helped. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yes thank you for the lead! It looked like there was a very old BOM import for all GCP libraries including BigQuery that was being prioritized over my current imports. Once that was resolved, I saw the BigNumber enumeration. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using versions [`1.124.7`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/1.124.7/index.html?com/google/cloud/bigquery/StandardSQLTypeName.html) and below, the enum for **StandardSQLTypeName.BIGNUMERIC** is not yet present. I suggest you use the latest version ([1.125.0](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/1.125.0/index.html?com/google/cloud/bigquery/StandardSQLTypeName.html) and up).

You can refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables) for a detailed guide on how to create and use BigQuery table.